# Interesting probability question, probability of getting right at this question of you check it at random.

Tags: probability

> If you check this question at random, find the probability that you get right at this question. $$ ① 20\% \quad ② 80\% \quad ③ 25\% \quad ④ 20\% \quad ⑤50\%$$

I'm afraid if I am just beside the MSE community guidelines...

Amazingly, this question is from the [Korean comedian's youtube.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IpNBS86Y9oU)

First, you can think that the answer is 1. Then, you will find that 4 is also 20%. So, you will say that 1 is as same as 4. Therefore, the answer is 3, 25%. But, you can also say that we have to choose the answer between 1 and 4, so the answer is also 5. Therefore, the answers are 1, 3, 4, and 5. So the probability of this is 2, 80%. Then, it brings a big contradiction. How can you solve this?

Comment: Tell me if this question is beside the MSE guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of guessing and choosing 2,3, or 5 are all 20%. Because each of these answers is not 20%, they are wrong. The probability of guessing and choosing 20% as an answer is 40%, so the answers that are 20% are wrong. There is no correct answer.

However, if you get this question on a test and know that there is 1 correct answer, then you would have a 20% chance of guessing it, so you would choose either 1 or 4.

There is no way to guarantee that you will get this problem correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I couldn't think that this has "no solution".